# Copy and paste fail in XeLaTeX Nono font

Tags: fonts, cjk, xelatex

I find numbers in files produced by `xelatex` with font `Noto CJK` is not copy-able, what's the wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % fontspec package requires either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}

\begin{document}
I have 120 apples
\end{document}
```

[image: Only numbers can't be copied]

Comment: No problem with mac preview or adobe reader https://i.stack.imgur.com/wip0q.png -- maybe a issue of the pdf viewer?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried with Linux Adobe 9, copy-paste of the numbers become tofus: I have  apples